# Frameworks that Abstract Away Main

Tags: c#, c++, architecture, wxwidgets

How is it possible for certain C++ & C# frameworks to run without requiring the users to implement a `main` function or class?

For example; in [MVVM Cross](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/n0-first-mvvmcross-application-n1-days.html) you implement your `MvxApplication` and everything goes from there. In [wxWidgets](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_helloworld.html) you implement your `wxApp`.

Do the frameworks implement main in their API's or do they completely bypass it? Is there a term for a framework design that abstracts away main? What is the benefit of this design?

Comment: If you start debugging step by step (F11 in Visual Studio) the execution should stop right at the start of the main function, no matter how well is hidden. Unless ofc if C# method has [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx), in which case you can override it in [debugger settings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1099949/395718).

Answer (score 1):

In wxWidgets case you still get `main()` or `WinMain()`, it is just hidden inside the `wxIMPLEMENT_APP()` macro. The main benefit is that you don't have to use conditional compilation in your own code to define `WinMain()` under Windows and `main()` elsewhere (in the past, there used to be other platforms which used something other than `main()`, but I believe they're all extinct by now).

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a `main`.  So these frameworks must provide there own `main` and then call their framework specific `main` (e.g. `MvXApplication`).

The reason they do this is because the framework must require certain starting/ending function calls or actions to take place before/after calling client code.  And these actions are probably too complicated or too numerous to require client code to do.

I don't know of a term or name for this.